# Semantic Consequence Definition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

"What is the difference between 
⊨
(semantic consequence) and 
⊢
(syntactic consequence)?" was a question that has been [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286077/implies-vs-entails-vs-provable), but I am wanting a more specific answer. For example, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3QFecRTkI4) explains what a syntactic consequence is. After watching this video, it is obvious that we say
p
⊢q
when p->q is a tautology where p and q are given propositions forming the tautology. What is an easy way to explain what a semantic consequence is? I have been obsessed looking at this question for awhile. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the post : [difference-between-syntactic-consequence-and-semantic-consequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365569/whats-the-difference-between-syntactic-consequence-%e2%8a%a2-and-semantic-consequence-%e2%8a%a8).

Comment: See also the post : [what-is-the-meaning-of-the-double-turnstile-symbol](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-double-turnstile-symbol-models)

Comment: See also the post : [why-are $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ symbols-from-metalanguage](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218354/why-are-vdash-and-vdash-symbols-from-metalanguage)

Comment: See also the post [meaning-of-symbols $\vdash$ and $\models$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115066/meaning-of-symbols-vdash-and-models)

Comment: I can not help but notice that you are the same person that wrote about the axiom for set theory. I am still confused with these symbols. I will read about them more. Can you explain them to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\vDash$ means: [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence).

The general definition of it is:

> A sentence $\varphi$ is said to be a *logical consequence* of a set of sentences $\Gamma$ (in symbols: $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$) if and only if there is no model $\mathcal {I}$ in which all members of $\Gamma$  are true and $\varphi$ is false.

In the context of propositional logic, this means that:

> for every *truth assignment* (or *valuation*) $v$, i.e. for every function that assign a truth-value (**T** or **F**) to every sentential letter occurring in the formulas in $\Gamma$ or $\varphi$, if $v$ *satisfy* every formulas in $\Gamma$, then it satisfy also $\varphi$.

Trivial example (where $\Gamma$ has only one formula):

> $\{ p \land q \} \vDash p$.

A truth assignment $v$ satisfy $p \land q$ only if $v(p)=v(q)=$ **T**.

Thus, every truth assignment $v$ that satisfy every formulas in $\Gamma$, i.e. that satisfy $p \land q$, satisfy also $p$.

---

$\Gamma \vdash_{\mathcal S} \varphi$, instead, means that $\varphi$ is *derivable* (in the *proof system* $\mathcal S$) from the set of *assumptions* $\Gamma$.

Comment: P= 1, 1, 0, 0 and Q=1, 0, 1, 0. Then, P^Q= 1, 0, 0, 0. Therefore, {P^Q} ⊨ P, since there is no combination where {P^Q}=1 and P would be a 0 correct? How would that be different from a syntactic consequence?

Comment: Your answer did help me though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

$\vdash$ is used to make statement about formal proof systems, which include rules of inference, that say:

"If you have a (or two) statement(s) that look like such-and-so, then you can write down a new statement that looks like this-and-that".

For example, many formal proof systems include the following rule of inference called Modus Ponens:

$$\varphi$$

$$\varphi \rightarrow \psi$$

$$\therefore \psi$$

So with this rule, I can, for example, infer $B \land C$ from $A$ and $A \rightarrow (B \land C)$. The fact that I can do this within the proof system we write as: $A, A \rightarrow (B \land C) \vdash B \land C$.

Now, as it so happens, $B \land C$ does in fact *logically follow* from $A$ and $A \rightarrow (B \land C)$. That is, the way we defined the formal semantics (think truth-tables) is such that whenever $A$ and $A \rightarrow (B \land C)$ are true, $B \land C$ will have to be true as well. And that we write as $A, A \rightarrow (B \land C) \vDash B \land C$.

But maybe the best way to illustrate the difference between $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ is to consider a case where they don't both hold at the same time.
So, suppose I write a new logic textbook, and suppose that I develop a very simple system for making formal proofs, in that it has a single rule of inference:

**Hokus Ponens**

$$\therefore \varphi$$

Now, with Hokus Ponens, I can derive anything from nothing. Thus, for example, it will be true that $P \vdash Q$. Here is the derivation/formal proof:

1. $P$ Premise
2. $Q$ Hokus Ponens!

But obviously, $Q$ does *not* logically follow from $P$. That is: $P \not \vDash Q$.