# theoretical question regarding deduction and relation between $\vdash$ and $\vDash$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

i have a very basic and theoritical question to help me understand the basics of logics and deduction systems. trying to understand the basics between the difference and deduction of $ \vdash$ $\vDash$ and the relation and deduction between them.

D is an deduction system of proposition calculus. it's axioms are all the propositions that are not tautologies and it's only deduction rule is: $\frac{a \lor b}{a \land b}$.

1)does it apply for every set of proposition x, so that $x \vdash a \Rightarrow x \vDash a$?

2)does $x \not \vDash a \Rightarrow x \vdash a$ ?

thank you very much for aiding me learn.

Comment: See posts [Why are $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ symbols from metalanguage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218354/why-are-vdash-and-vdash-symbols-from-metalanguage) and [Meaning of symbols $\vdash$  and $\models$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115066/meaning-of-symbols-vdash-and-models).

Answer (score 4):

You have to prove a sort of soundness theorem for your calculus.

*Hint* about *soundness* :

> if $\Gamma \vdash a$, the $\Gamma \vDash a$.

Assume that $\Gamma \vdash a$ and consider the ususal cases :

*(i)* $a \in \Gamma$; then obviously $\Gamma \vDash a$, because every assignment $v$ that satisfies every formula in $\Gamma$ will satisfies also $a$.

*(ii)* $a$ is an *axiom*; this means that $a$ is **not** a *tautology*. Consider the case $a := p$.

According to the definition of derivation, we have $\{ q \lor r \} \vdash p$, but obviously : $\{ q \lor r \} \nvDash p$.

*(iii)* $a$ is derived with the inference rule from a previous formula in the derivation.